# Taking screenshots when I'm not logged in

Tags: batch, scheduled-tasks, screenshot

I'm looking to take several screenshots from an application at a certain time of the day (let's say 3 o'clock, when I'm certainly not logged in) .
Currently I'm using NirCmd to take the screenshots, but if I schedule the execution (to run even when I'm not logged in, as I wish) I get a black screen.

Is there a way to "create" the desktop, even if I'm not really logged in (so that I'll have something different from a black screenshot)?

Comment: I think you'll need to be logged in to take a screen shot of what's up on the desktop. If no one is logged on and the process runs whether logged on or not, then I believe this is the expected behavior of the command driven screen print unfortunately.  You may want to just ensure that there is someone logged onto the PC at these times if the process is critical or else see if you can figure out a way to log in via some process perhaps which would be an entirely different question.

Comment: I hoped it wasn't something like that... I'll leave the question open, just in case

Comment: When you said you wanted a screenshot of the application at a certain time of the day, I'm assuming you are leaving your PC on, and you are logged in, and the application running, just you are not physically in front of the machine at the time to do the actual screenshot? You just wanted the screenshot process to be done automatically? Or you will be completely logged off, and you need the automation to run the application, and take screenshot, and log out again?

Comment: I'll have the pc on, and the user I use to take the screenshots (which is NOT my user, this one has some limitations on what it sees on the app) will be logged off. I already have the piece of code that opens the application and take the screenshot, I just need to make it really "see" the desktop when I schedule the task

Comment: Not going to happen. When you set a task to run when not logged in, it is an non interactive session so it does not interact with the desktop.