# How to login a user from batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, login, windows-task-scheduler, auto-login

I'm looking for a way to login a user at a certain time of the day (for example 3 o'clock, when I'm most certainly not logged in), take some screenshot and then logout.

As you can see from my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1018839/taking-screenshots-when-im-not-logged-in), it would be really likely to do this from batch (so that I can easily schedule all the process from Window's Task Scheduler), but I'm open to any other solution.
If possible, I would avoid the auto-logon feature

Do you have any idea about how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to just have the task run as `INTERACTIVE`, since there won't be anything interesting to take a screenshot of unless *somebody* is logged in. More details and the motivation for this request might help us solve your real problem.

Comment: Sorry, forget my previous comment, it was wrong. To clarify things, I currently have a batch that opens an application. Using `MirCmd` I take some screenshots and then using `Image Magick` I crop them. The bat itself works just fine when I try it, but what I want to achieve is schedule a user (which will not be my own one) to log and run that bat. I've tried, as you suggested, the `INTERACTIVE`, but using that I would need to manually log (so nothing changes). What I need is to log a user in the proper way to make it able to take screenshots